# How do I substitute one word in a string variable in Python?

Tags: python, python-2.7, replace, substitution

I know people have asked about how to substitute words in strings, but I'd like to replace a specific word in a variable string, and leave the rest untouched.

For example: if the user enters "My family does not like chicken", I'd like the computer to output back to them "Your family does not like chicken". The word being replaced is "My", and the word replacing it is "Your". I'm using Python 2.7.13.

Comment: Please show us what you have tried in code. The answer will be far more meaningful if we can address your misunderstanding at the same time. Have you looked at `replace()` for example; did it not work?

Comment: I misunderstood the use of replace(). I am sorry!

Answer (score 3):

Use the [`replace()`](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/string_replace.htm) string method:

```
>>> "My family does not like chicken".replace("My", "Your")
Your family does not like chicken
```

Answer (score 1):

The other answers do not deal with storing user input, you can do so by using [`raw_input`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#raw_input) in python 2:

```
#Store users input into a variable
user_input = raw_input("Please enter a sentence: ")

#Use str.replace to replace ALL occurrences of the word "My" with "Your" and output using print
print user_input.replace("My", "Your")
```

**Example Usage:**

```
Please enter a sentence:  My family does not like chicken
Your family does not like chicken
```

Try it [here!](https://repl.it/GjD1/1)

***Link to python documentation for:*** [`str.replace`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#string.replace)

Comment: This is exactly what I needed. Thank you!

Comment: @Jalonzpa You should accept this answer, then. Click the check mark below the number on the left of this answer, it will turn green.

Answer (score -2):

Use the replace() function

```
oldstr = 'my family does not like chicken'
newstr = oldstr.replace('my', 'your')
print(newstr)
```

Output
    your family does not like chicken